# Why is 'Windows Installer XML" missing from New Projects in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I had previously installed WIX 3.8, and could see the "Windows Installer XML" selection when creating a new project in VS 2012.  I downloaded and installed VS 2013 Ultimate, with SP1.  I did a Repair on WIX, and I did see it referencing VS 2013.  But when I go to create a new project in VS 2013, the "Windows Installer XML" does not show.

When I look at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Wix, it only has a "ProjectTemplates" folder with three zip files in it.  The same folder in VS 2012 has a number of items in it.

What do I need to do to correct this (Do the trial versions of VS preclude this from working)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem, you cannot do a repair as it won't try to re-detect the VS2013 installation. Just uninstall Wix completely and re-install and it will then work.

Comment: You should accept it then, click the big tick next to it! :)

Comment: With VS 2015, I had the Windows Installer XML template entry, but not the actual project templates. The uninstall/reinstall of 3.10 did the trick.